# How to change test message Format as null through IBM Websphere MQ Explorer

Tags: linux, mq

We're using IBM Websphere MQ Explorer and when we are checking the format of test message it's MQSTR. Is there any way in which I can change the format to null.
Can we change it through JMSSTUB and if yes, then how.
My main concern is to make the format null.
Is there any command on linux to change the property of queue format as null.

I tried to change it in the log4j file by creating new param entry but still unable to achieve the result.

Comment: Why do you want to change the format to null?

Comment: For some issue we have to change it to null, to reproduce the MQGet with error code 2110 (Format error).

Comment: Why not set the message payload to something that isn't a string?